# How to pass whole statements as function parameters? python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this `dict`

```py
dic = {'wow': 77, 'yy': 'gt', 'dwe': {'dwdw': {'fefe': 2006}}}
```

and I have this function

```py
def get_missing_key(data, nest, default_value):
    try:
        return data + nest
    except KeyError as err:
        return default_value
```

and this is how I call it:

```py
get_missing_key(dic, ['dwe']['dwdw']['fefe'], 16)
```

What I want is that I want the second parameter to get converted to normal python expression and do calculations with it

I want it to be like this

```py
def get_missing_key(data, nest, default_value):
    try:
        return data['dwe']['dwdw']['fefe']
    except KeyError as err:
        return default_value
```

is there a way to achieve this?

But what I have clearly doesn't work, since I can't concatinate a `dict` with a `list`

Comment: `data + nest` isn't really the problem. `['dwe']['dwdw']['fefe']` take the list `['dwd']` and tries to index it with the string `dwdw`. That raises a `TypeError` immediately, preventing `get_missing_key` from every being called. `data` would a `dict`, but `nest` never gets initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use reduce like @kyle-parsons did, or you could manually loop:

```py
lookup = ["dwe", "dwdw", "fefe"]

def find_missing(data, lookup, default):
    found = data
    for i in lookup:
        try:
            found = found[i]
        except KeyError:
            return default

    return found
```

Comment: A couple of other suggestions, making this more similar to existing callable like `dict.get` and `operator.itemgetter`: make the definition `find_missing(data, *lookup, *, default=None)`, so that the call would look like `find_missing(dic, "dwe", "dwdw", "fefe")` or `find_missing(dic, *lookup)` or `find_missing(dic, *lookup, default=3)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your keys as a list.

```
from functools import reduce

def get_missing_key(data, nest, default_value):
    try:
        reduce(dict.__getitem__, nest, data)
    except KeyError:
        return default_value
```

In general, Python eagerly evaluates expressions and there's no way to delay that short of passing in strings of code to be built up and `exec`ed, but that's really not a good idea.